# PDF document spellchecker

Tags: pdf, spell-check

I am looking for a spellchecker for PDF documents.

Preferably it would process the PDF and mark any errors in the document.

Preferably it would use hunspell dictionaries

Comment: What operating system are you using? Why don't you want to spell check the source document instead?

Comment: Windows, Linux. Preferably linux. Source is Docbook see http://superuser.com/questions/204227/spellchecker-for-docbook

I have gotten limited support for spellchecking in dockbook working through XML Mind and I have also tried Aspell but those dictionaries are pretty weak - so this is a longshot :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many programs that allow you to activate mouse "right-click" (or any other selected button), on-spot translation (from all languages to all languages)

The most popular two are:
 1. Babylon
 2. White Smoke

Best of luck!

Comment: be sure and check out this post for how to do comment replies: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work