# Spellchecker for docbook

Tags: spell-check, docbook

Is there any good command line spellcheckers for Docbook avaliable that could be configured to ignore certain tags such as <programlisting>.

Preferably it would use hunspell dictionaries since I have a good [Swedish dictionary](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries) to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspell provides multiple operating modes to work in.

```
--mode=<string>, -e, -H, -t, -n
  Sets the filter mode.  Mode is one of none, url, email, html, tex or nroff. 
  The  alternative  shortcut  options  are  '-e'  for  email,  '-H'  for
  Html/Sgml, '-t' for Tex or '-n' for Nroff.
```

Sounds like you just need to install the hunspell dictionaries and then you can run aspell with the -H (--mode=Html/Sgml) option.

Comment: I can use hunspell dictionaries  with a spell, ok will check